# help for better circuitikz code

Tags: circuitikz

Does someone know how to get this result easier (without define the text in x/y-coordinates) and with possibilitiy of linebreaks?

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1]
% How can I get this easier?
% Like this, but it does not work
% \node [ocirc, label=left:left-aligned{VCC1 out\newline IC523}] (z) at (2,1.5) {};
\node [ocirc, label={[xshift=-1.15cm, yshift=-0.1cm]VCC1 out}] (y) at (2,1.5) {};
\node [ocirc, label={[xshift=-1.0cm, yshift=-0.5cm]of IC523}] (x) at (2,1.5) {};
% 
\draw [short,-o] (2,1.5) to [R, l_=$R1$] (5,1.5) to [short,-*] (5,1.5);
\draw (2,1.5) to [R,  l=$30 Ohm$] (5,1.5);
% how to define ``R2'' and ``30 Ohm'' in one line?
% \draw (5,1.5) to [R, l_=$R2$, l=$30 Ohm$] (8,1.5) to [short,-*] (8,1.5);
% does not work
\draw (5,1.5) to [R, l_=$R2$] (8,1.5) to [short,-*] (8,1.5);
\draw (5,1.5) to [R, l=$30 Ohm$] (8,1.5);
%
\draw (8,1.5) to [C, l_=$C$] (11,1.5) to [short,-o] (11,1.5);
%How can I get MKS4-100 $100nF$ $100V$ RM7.5 in 4 lines?
% \draw (8,1.5) to [C, l=MKS4-100 \newline $100nF$ \newline $100V$ \newline RM7.5] (11,1.5);
% does not work
\draw (8,1.5) to [C, l=MKS4-100 $100nF$ $100V$ RM7.5] (11,1.5);
\node [ocirc, label=right:{out}] (y) at (11,1.5) {};

 \end{circuitikz} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: I edited my answer a bit after you accepted it, removing a bit more unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the standard label, added with `l`, there is the possibility to add an "annotation", with `a`. Both can have `_` or `^` after it to set the position. So you can do `l_={..},a^={..}`.

For nodes, you can add `align=left` (or `center` or `right`) to the options, and then you can use `\\` to add a line break. I'm not very familiar with `circuitikz`, so I don't know how to add that style to a `l` label though, so I used a `tabular` instead, for the four-line label.

Note also the use of `siunitx` to write numbers with units. In general you can use `\SI{number}{unit}`, for `circuitikz` labels/annotations you use the shorthand `number<unit>`, as in the code below.

The entire thing can be written as a single path, without any repetitions of coordinates, as seen below:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1]
\draw [short,-o] (2,1.5)
   node[ocirc,label={[align=left]left:VCC1 out\\of IC523}]{}
 to [R, l_=$R_1$,a^=30<\ohm>,-*] (5,1.5)
 to [R,l_=$R_2$,a^=30<\ohm>,-*] (8,1.5) 
 to [C, l_=$C$,a^={%
        \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
           MKS4-100\\
           \SI{100}{\nano\farad}\\
           \SI{100}{\volt}\\
           RM7.5
         \end{tabular}}
     ] (11,1.5)
  node[right]{out};

\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. You need a quite new version of `circuitikz`, tough...  it's nice that you can download it as a single file from http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/

Comment: @Rmano Not exactly bleeding edge though. The annotation feature was added in version 0.7, in September of last year. I have the one in TeX Live 2017, which is version 0.8.3.